# wordpress woocommerce store taking too many requests

Tags: .net, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, httprequest

website - www.inoventary.com

product page - https://www.inoventary.com/product/beautiful-3d-flower-design-cases/

while I am opening any page on my website even product page it is taking too many request due to which its wait time is too high, in my opinion it is due to problem in theme or in its in built plugin like slick slider which we can't uninstall but I am not sure.

How to fix that?

Comment: What do you mean with "which we can't uniinstall". Also ¿Had you tried to deactivate all plugins, changing to a basic theme (for example, Storefront) and see if that changes the load speed of your site? ¿What are the Specs of your Hosting?

Comment: @Syntax_Error I have tried storefront but same issue while loading product pages

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the issue with WooCommerce being slow is due to being on a sub-par, shared web host. You probably need to get on a better hosting solution. Good luck!